# {Done] Permissions for Data folder on external Harddrive

Tags: permissions, installation, raspberry-pi, hard-drive, nextcloud

So i reinstalled Nextcloud on my Pi, because i got now an external harddrive to connect. So i used:
sudo ln -s media/pi/Elementals/Nextcloud/data /var/www/nextcloud/data

and i changed the the owner inside var /www/nextcloud to www-data for the data folder there.
Still i cant install it. I tried to change the owner of /media/pi/Elementals/Nextcloud/data. But cant change it.
im using:
chown -R www-data:www-data data/
Even thos when i use:
sudo -u www-data bash
and then create a folder its owned by pi.
What i did wrong ?

### Got it:

used fstab used there ntfs-3g

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add `sudo` the command should be

`sudo chown www-data /path/to/data/`

Comment: im logged in as root, but sudo didnt change anything

Comment: can you try running `cd /media/pi/Elementals/Nextcloud/ ` then `ls -all` and then give me the output

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dez 28 15:31 .

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:30 ..

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:31 data`

"For some reason i solved this problem but now i got this one:
Please change the permissions to so that the directory cannot be listed by other users."

Comment: from the folder I specified can you try running `sudo chown root:www-data /data/` and then show me the output of `ls -all`

Comment: you could try `sudo chmod o-rwx /data/`

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dez 28 15:31 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:31 data`

Comment: I tried: `sudo chmod o-rwx /data/`

still this: _Please change the permissions to so that the directory cannot be listed by other users._

Comment: sorry for asking to for you to run the command again and again, but I require that information to pinpoint the issue

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dez 28 15:31 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dez 28 15:31 data`

Comment: It seems like you are not able to change the permissions on the folder

Comment: Maybe something with ntfs formats ?
how i can i fromat to smthing else ?